# Question about Riemann-Stieltjes problem with Euler

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis

Use Euler summation formula and integration by parts to show that

$$
\int_1^3 \left(\frac{[[x]]}{x^3}\right)dx = \frac{37}{72}
$$

Sorry I'm still learning how to use MathJax or how to put math formulas into the text...

Currently, I'm an undergraduate studying Math Analysis. Any help would be greatly appreaciated! Thanks for your time

Comment: What does the double-bracket mean?

Comment: If $[[x]]$ means integer part of $x$ then you can split the integral into intervals $[1,2]$ and $[2,3]$.

Comment: @Oighea Yes, indeed, it is the integer part of x

Comment: That is equivalent to the floor of x.

Answer (score 1):

Use the real function defined by $f(x)=\frac{-1}{2x^2}\Rightarrow f'(x)=\frac{1}{x^3}$

Euler summation formula implies:

$$\sum_{n=1}^3f(n)=\int_1^3f(x)dx+\int_1^3f'(x)(x-[|x|]-\frac{1}{2})dx+\frac{f(1)+f(3)}{2}$$
$$\sum_{n=1}^3(\frac{-1}{2n^2})=\int_1^3\frac{-1}{2x^2}dx+\int_1^3\frac{1}{x^3}(x-[|x|]-\frac{1}{2})dx-\frac{5}{18}$$
$$\sum_{n=1}^3(\frac{-1}{2n^2})=\int_1^3\frac{-1}{2x^2}dx+\int_1^3\frac{1}{x^2}dx-\int_1^3\frac{[|x|]}{x^3}dx-\frac{1}{2}\int_1^3\frac{1}{x^3}dx-\frac{5}{18}$$
Thus, you will get:

$$\int_1^3\frac{[|x|]}{x^3}dx=\int_1^3\frac{-1}{2x^2}dx+\int_1^3\frac{1}{x^2}dx-\frac{1}{2}\int_1^3\frac{1}{x^3}dx-\frac{5}{18}-\sum_{n=1}^3(\frac{-1}{2n^2})=\frac{37}{72}$$